# errbit on synology docker returns 127.0.0.1:27017 => connection refused

Tags: docker, synology, errbit

i'm facing an issue with errbit installed in my synology docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/errbit/errbit

i can run the app but the app can't connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 => connection refused.

the docker file has mongodb inside. The docker is on the bridge network.

Any idea?

Comment: What's your deployment scenario like? Are you running both mongo and errbit inside docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

Running `docker-compose up` brings up both Errbit and Mongo containers. In this scenario Errbit can reach Mongo. And the database can be seeded with: `docker exec errbit_errbit_1 bundle exec rake errbit:bootstrap`.

If you add some more info to your question about exactly how you're deploying Errbit, I can probably add a bit more help.

Also, very cool to see someone deploying Errbit to a Synology box!

Comment: Hey @stepen. I did that several days ago and it works! that